# iTextSharp can't read numbers in this PDF

Tags: pdf, itext

I'm reading PDF by iTextSharp-5.5.7.0, PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage() works well in most of files until this: [sample PDF](http://www.bnpparibas-ip.sg/doc/fact/FACTSHEET05ENSG07100715FO02332302.pdf)

I can't read any number from it, for example: only return 'ANEU' from 'A0NE8U', they are fine in Adobe Reader to copy out. Code is here:

```
public static string ExtractTextFromPdf(string path)
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
    {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
        }

        return text.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you try copy&paste from Adobe Reader, you get **AƹNEǁU** instead of *A0NE8U*. As text extraction in Adobe Reader is fairly good, this indicates that the information on the Unicode characters to associate with those digit glyphs are missing or wrong in the PDF, by accident or probably even deliberately to prevent text extraction.

Comment: @mkl: usually Acrobat beats the crap out of 3rd party tools. My Acrobat Pro 9 also has no problem with this file and copies this text in box under "CODES" perfectly. Verifying the file confirms that it has a correct `/ToUnicode` entry for the font. It must be a limitation of iTextSharp.

Comment: @Jongware Oops, you're right. It seems like (for the result above) I actually did not c&p from Adobe Reader but from the Chrome PDF viewer. I stand corrected...

Comment: @Jongware Actually, I tried other 3rd party tools, such as PdfBox which is fine in this question.

Answer (score 3):

The font in question has a **ToUnicode** map which is used for text extraction. Unfortunately, though, iText(Sharp) reads it only partially, and digits are located after the mappings read.

---

**In detail:**

The cause for the issue is the implementation of `AbstractCMap.addRange` (I'm showing the iText Java code as iText also has this issue and I'm more into the Java version):

```
void addRange(PdfString from, PdfString to, PdfObject code) {
    byte[] a1 = decodeStringToByte(from);
    byte[] a2 = decodeStringToByte(to);
    if (a1.length != a2.length || a1.length == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid map.");
    byte[] sout = null;
    if (code instanceof PdfString)
        sout = decodeStringToByte((PdfString)code);
    int start = a1[a1.length - 1] & 0xff;
    int end = a2[a2.length - 1] & 0xff;
    for (int k = start; k <= end; ++k) {
        a1[a1.length - 1] = (byte)k;
        PdfString s = new PdfString(a1);
        s.setHexWriting(true);
        if (code instanceof PdfArray) {
            addChar(s, ((PdfArray)code).getPdfObject(k - start));
        }
        else if (code instanceof PdfNumber) {
            int nn = ((PdfNumber)code).intValue() + k - start;
            addChar(s, new PdfNumber(nn));
        }
        else if (code instanceof PdfString) {
            PdfString s1 = new PdfString(sout);
            s1.setHexWriting(true);
            ++sout[sout.length - 1];
            addChar(s, s1);
        }
    }
}
```

The loop only considers the range in the least significant byte of `from` and `to`. Thus, for the range in question:

```
1 beginbfrange
<0000><01E1>[
<FFFD><FFFD><FFFD><0020><0041><0042><0043><0044>
<0045><0046><0047><0048><0049><004A><004B><004C> 
...
<2248><003C><003E><2264><2265><00AC><0394><03A9>
<00B5><03C0><00B0><221E><2202><222B><221A><2211>
<220F><25CA>]
endbfrange
```

it only iterates from 0x00 to 0xE1, i.e. only the first 226 entries of the 482 mappings.

---

There actually are some peculiar restrictions in CMaps, e.g. there may only be up to 100 separate bfrange entries in the same section, and in the alternative bfrange entry syntax

```
n beginbfrange
srcCode1 srcCode2 dstString
endbfrange
```

which is handled by the same method `addRange`, there is the restriction

> When defining ranges of this type, the value of the last byte in the string shall be less than or equal to `255 − (srcCode2 − srcCode1)`.

Probably a misunderstanding of this restriction made the developer believe, `srcCode2` and `srcCode1` also would merely differ in the least significant byte.

But maybe there are even more restrictions which I merely did not find...

---

**Meanwhile** (as of iText 5.5.9, tested against a development SNAPSHOT) this issue seems to have been fixed.

Comment: According to "Technical Note #5411 ToUnicode Mapping File Tutorial" in section 1.4.1 CautionaryNotes "when using “bfrange” operators, care must be taken not to cross first-byte boundaries for 
the CID values in a single mapping line" and give the example of <10FE> <1101> being incorrect and needing to be split in two lines. I very much suspect that the ToUnicade is invalid but, as usually, Adobe is too lenient with what it accepts and everybody else will have to follow suit.

Comment: That might be a *restriction which I merely did not find*.  In the case at hand we may cross a first byte boundary but the code is not equipped to even cross a second to last byte boundary.

Comment: Having looked at that sample I have to point out that it is about the other kind of bfrange. Is there any indication that the bfranges of the kind at hand may not cross first byte boundaries? There should be something more conclusive than such an example. Otherwise that hardly  be counted on as being a ruling.

Comment: I think the topic is moot. If Acrobat does it so must iText. The iText log is sprinkled with fixes to out of specs (or alleged) PDFs, this will be another.

Comment: PDF Ref, 5.9.2 ToUnicode CMaps:  "When defining ranges of this type, care must be taken to ensure that the value of the last byte in the string is less than or equal to 255" (i.e., end minus start). So the sample file violates this rule, doesn't it? No! This file uses the *second* notation using *ranges*, and that restriction is *not* mentioned. (This second notation is **not** addressed in the "ToUnicode Mapping File
Tutorial".)

Comment: This was very useful in repairing the PDF I was having issues with (the to value was 00FF, I just dropped the first byte manually from the PDF). It's worth noting that this is still the same code in Android's iTextG 5.5.10 package.